# Post XML value with form

Tags: php, xml, forms, xpath

I have integrated an XPath search to my site, when a user searches they are presented with their results as well as a check box for each, shown in the following way.

```
<form action="saveProcess.php" method="POST">
            <?php
            foreach ($holidays as $holiday) 
            {
                $resultTable .=  "<p><a href=\"{$holiday->link}\">{$holiday->title}</a>" . "<br/>" . 
                "{$holiday->pubDate}" . "<br>" . 
                "{$holiday->description}" . 
                "<input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='{$holiday->title}' />" . "<br /></p>";              
            }
            ?>
            <input type="submit"  name="btnOutput" value="submit"/>
        </form>
```

When a check box is clicked and the submit button clicked i want the value of `{$holiday->title}` to be posted to `saveProcess.php` and echoed. currently i am met with the error `Notice: Undefined index: chk in saveProcess.php`

```
<?php
    $title = $_POST['chk']
    echo $title;
?>
```

What is the reason for this? could it be that the XML file is not instantiated within the saveProcess.php file or is there a syntax error I'm not seeing?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see anything when you do `<?php echo print_r($_POST); ?>` in saveProcess.php?

Comment: I see `Array ( [btnOutput] => submit ) 1 `

Comment: In Firebug, can you see the checkbox element? Make sure it has 'chk' as a name

Comment: In saveProcess.php all i see in the firebug post is `btnOutput submit`

Comment: No, what do you see in your main file's form?

Comment: Sorry, no good with firebug. Can only see the form action and the submit button in the main form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you're *echoing out* anything.  You need to use:

```
<?php
   $resultTable = '';
   foreach ($holidays as $holiday) 
   {
      $resultTable .=  "<p><a href=\"{$holiday->link}\">{$holiday->title}</a>" . "<br/>" . "{$holiday->pubDate}" . "<br>" . "{$holiday->description}" . "<input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='{$holiday->title}' />" . "<br /></p>";              
   }
   echo $resultTable;
?>
```

Because your element has `[]` at the end of its name, it indicates that you want to its $_POST value as part of an array. It will look like this in PHP:

```
array(0 => 'First value', 1 => 'Second value', 2 => 'Third value)
```

You can loop through it if you need to process each value individually:

```
foreach($_POST['chk'] as $check_value)
{
   // process $check_value
}
```

Comment: When i now submit i am given the output `Array` in saveProcess not the {$holiday->title}?

Comment: Because it's a checkbox with `[]` in its name, it converts the $_POST value to an array. See my updated answer for an explanation

Comment: Thanks @Jamie makes much more sense now.